# What is known about the Heronian primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

A Diophantine equation $$x^3 - Dy^3 = 1$$ always has a trivial solution $x = y^3 + 1$. It appears that a non-trivial (that is those with $x$ smaller than trivial) solution exists *iff* $y$ is a [Heronian integer](http://oeis.org/A135412) (that is $y = \frac{a + \sqrt{ab} + b}{3}$ for some integers $a \ne b$).

*Obviously* prime $y$s give the most interesting solutions. Which raises the actual question:

```
What is known about the Heronian primes?
```

Comment: What is $D,$ and why is $x=y^3 + 1$ a solution of $x^3 - D y^3 = 1?$

Comment: @WillJagy D is an integer. It is a solution because $x^3 -Dy^3 = (y^3 + 1)^3 - Dy^3 = y^9 + 3 y^6 + 3y^3 + 1 - Dy^3 = y^3(y^6 + 3y^3 + 3y - D) + 1$. The trivial solution is obtained by setting $D = y^6 + 3y^3 + 3y$.